# Google translate api on android gives error 'GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request'

Tags: java, android, google-translate, android-studio-3.0

When trying to access google translate api from an android application it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
....
Caused by: com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: Invalid Value
...
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Invalid Value",
"reason" : "invalid"
} ],
"message" : "Invalid Value"
```

The code inside doInBackground method() is:

```
 Translate translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder()
                .setApiKey("myAPI_key").build().getService();

        Translation translation = translate.translate(
                params[0],
                Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("al"));


        return translation.getTranslatedText();                                                }
```

The string I pass is in english. Can anyone help me figuring out this error? 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("al"));
```

**al** is not a correct code for any supported language.

You can check the complete list of supported languages in the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/translation/translate/v2/language.languages.list).

Comment: I realized that after I posted the question. Anyway thanks.